# camel-spring.xsd is missing in camel-spring-3.10.0.jar

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have upgraded the camel version to latest and found that xsd is missing in the jar file. The xsd file is available in camel-spring-3.8.0.jar. Due to this am getting exception in spring camel application.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out finally. The camel-spring component has been modularized into:

camel-spring - Core module for Camel Spring support

camel-spring-xml - XML DSL when using Spring XML (eg )

The xsds are defined in camel-spring-xml. Added the dependency fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Struggling for hours to find out this. :(